# Copy Network file to local drive

Tags: delphi, windows-10

I am trying to copy a file from a network to a local drive.  The file is a mdb database file.  When the program fails I get the following message:

> "Failed to copy network file N:\tmp\ArchiveTest\Archive.mdb to C:\tmp\OldArchive.mdb.  The system cannot find the path specified."

The OS I am using is Windows 10.

```
if not CopyFile(pchar(ArchiveDataFolder), pchar('C:\tmp\OldArchive.mdb'), False) then begin
  ShowMessage('Failed to copy network file '+ArchiveDataFolder+' to C:\tmp\OldArchive.mdb '+SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  Exit;
end;
```

Comment: Did you check if "C:\tmp" is is found and if you have rights to write in it? Or try to set the third parameter to true if the file is already there

Comment: Yes, C:\tmp exists and I have rights to copy there.

Comment: @Christine - before I have ran each test I have made sure that the file did not exist in the folder C:\tmp.  This process works when I'm copying from a local source but when the file is on the network it will not copy.

Comment: Is it a program you're making or a service? Also, under what user are you running your program? The same user as the logged in user? Network drives are user specific in windows 10 and if you work as a normal user, but run your program as administrator, the network drives may not exist for the administrator user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `ArchiveDataFolder` has the value that you state, the error tells you that the process cannot find either `N:\tmp\ArchiveTest` or `C:\tmp`. Presumably you have checked that the paths exist. If they do then the likely cause is that the process runs in a context that does not have the network drive letter mapped.

Comment: I changed the code to reference the network file with its server path \\Hermes\Apps\tmp\ArchiveTest\Archive.mdb and it copies the file fine now.  Is there a good way to find out the server path mapped to the drive letter?  This will be running on computers where I wont know the network path but just the mapped the drive letter.

Comment: Sorry, I just answered the question you asked. Can we deal with that first. If you have a different question, ask a different question.

Comment: Thank you but your help has just lead me to another island. If I cannot obtain the path that is mapped to the network drive then the solution is not useful.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Our task it to answer your questions, not solve all subsequent problems. This answers the question that was asked.

Comment: Open a new question Lou. This site not only helps you, but it also helps other people that can face the same problem in the future. If different issues are solved on the same thread, it makes it very difficult for other people to search and find the solution. On the other hand, having a different question for every issue (even related ones) makes it cleaner and easier to find.

Comment: Thank you everyone

Comment: Partially answered but still does not resolve the problem. I cannot post another question for 4 days so I guess I wait until then to try to explain.  If I cannot access the UNC from ExpandUNCFileName function or similar then its irrelevant that using the UNC will fix my problem.

Comment: I think you have not appreciated how this site works. We answer questions. One at a time. If they lead to further questions, that's for another time. There is nothing partial about this. There's nothing more that can said, given the question that was asked. It is also perhaps worth pointing out that you didn't actually ask a question.